# Keplerian orbits are intersections of planes with the the future light-cone in Minkowski 4-space

Tags: special-relativity, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Near the end of [this essay](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gravitational.html), Baez comments:

> In 2011, Guowu Meng pointed out a remarkable fact to me. Orbits of the
> Kepler problem are precisely the intersections of 2-dimensional planes
> with this cone
>
> $$ \{(t,x,y,z) : t^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = 0, t > 0\}$$

I would like to know why is this true. I did check out the references he provides but they seemed to be more concerned with generalizations of the Kepler problem than the original one.

Comment: I don't see how this can be true, as when t goes to infinity, the cone occupies points in space which are increasingly far away. A Kepler orbit has bounded x,y,z for all time.

Comment: @Myridium It doesn't give you orbits in spacetime, but does (I guess) give you conic sections.

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with the following argument: let the plane be $\mathbf u+a\mathbf v+b\mathbf w$ with $\mathbf u^2=\mathbf v^2=1$ (spacelike) and $\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf w=0$. You may as well take $\mathbf v=\hat{\mathbf x}$, and then a $yz$ rotation followed by a $ty$ boost makes $\mathbf w=\hat{\mathbf y}$, and you obviously get only circles. Maybe you get other shapes in planes with other metric signatures, but I don't understand what it means to say they're Kepler shapes when the metric is wrong.

Comment: @Myridium: I don't really understand your objection. Not all Kepler orbits are bounded, only the ones with negative energy.

Comment: @benrg: I don't understand yours either; the Minkowski metric doesn't necessarily have anything to do with this (as far as I can tell). In particular I don't think the situation is invariant under Lorentz transformations.

Comment: I suppose this is my fault for using "Minkowski" in the title, I didn't think it through when writing that. I think I can't edit the title though.

Comment: @Pedro The rest of the sentence of Baez's that you quoted is "in 4-dimensional Minkowski spacetime!" so I think your title is correct. Without the Minkowski metric, he's merely saying that Kepler orbits are conic sections, a fact that I'm quite sure he knew long before 2011. If your question is why Kepler orbits are conic sections, there may be a previous Physics SE question covering it.

Comment: I suppose you could say it's just asking why are orbits conics, but I'd make two points: 1) this is a 3-dimensional cone rather than a 2-dimensional one (i'm not sure this makes a difference), and 2) i don't know of any way to show keplerian orbits are conics by directly obtaining them as planar sections of some cone -- and i would find it very interesting to learn some.

Comment: Either Baez meant an intersection of a 2D plane of spacetime with the null spacetime cone mentioned, in which case he is wrong, or he meant that orbits are conic sections, in which case mentioning relativity or spacetime is superfluous and misleading.

Comment: I think he meant the former; why is he wrong?